# How to install mysql5 client in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, mysql

I have ubuntu 22.04 and my current mysql client is at version: `Ver 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))` located at: `/usr/bin/mysql`. However when I try to connect to a database server I get: `ERROR 1043 (08S01): Bad handshake`

From what I have read, It seems that the solution to the above is to install a mysql5 client because the server is older than the client.

How can I do this in my ubuntu system?

Comment: Which version of MySQL is the server running? Some of the early 5.x releases do not have clients that work on newer OSes due to deprecated (insecure) encryption mechanisms 

Comment: You have to install it from source, I have done this countless times in 20.04, not sure in 22.04.

Comment: @matigo The version is `5.7`

Comment: @Liso Can you please provide the link for downloading mysql cli-5.7 source?